# Linux PPTP VPN server using local account passwords?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, pptp, pptpd

Is there a way to configure the PPTP server under Ubuntu 10.04 to allow users to log in with their username/password from the local machine (the Ubuntu server, that is, not where they are connecting from)?  I don't want to have to add a new username to `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets` every time I create a user, nor do I particularly want to store passwords in plain text like that.

Comment: PPTP encryption is fundamentally broken.  Unless it is used briefly and casually, OR you're *forced* to use it for whatever reason, I'd think about looking at other solutions.  (see http://www.sans.org/security-resources/malwarefaq/pptp-vpn.php)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to store them crypted, because pptpd does CHAP which is a challenge response procedure. Your server needs your password in cleartext to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The option is called "`login`":

> Use the system password database for authenticating the peer using PAP, and record the user in the system wtmp file.  Note that the peer must have an entry in the /etc/ppp/pap-secrets file as well as the system password database to be allowed access.

Now you would need `require-pap` since users would have to send theirs passwords unencrypted but that's starting smell as PBP (Pretty Bad Privacy), isn't it? Also, it is PBP [even with MPPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pptp#Security_of_the_PPTP_protocol).

So, concluding, that was bad idea.